# Upgrading PHP results in SMTP authorization failure

Tags: php, email, smtp

I upgrade my PHP on centos server to 5.6.25
After upgrade is done everything working fine but after few hours I received a call from my client that outgoing mails are not delivered to recipient.

Then I found that outgoing mails are delivering from webmail but mails which are sent using our PHP code are not delivered.

After checking the result of PHP code I found the error

**authentication failure [SMTP: STARTTLS failed (code: 220, response: TLS go ahead)]**

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to this problem...

Just go to **usr/local/lib/php/Net** path may be differ from OS to OS but finally it is Net directory in php directory.

find file SMTP.php in this directory.
In this file find the function auth(--parameter list--) in this file he first if statement is

```
if ($tls && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.0', '>=')
        && extension_loaded('openssl') && isset($this->esmtp['STARTTLS'])
        && strncasecmp($this->host, 'ssl://', 6) !== 0
    )
```

just make change as follows

```
if ($tls && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '6.1.0', '>=')
        && extension_loaded('openssl') && isset($this->esmtp['STARTTLS'])
        && strncasecmp($this->host, 'ssl://', 6) !== 0
    )
```

as I have updated the system it is now getting following condition true and it is checking for openssl and STARTTLS and system fails at this stage

```
version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.0', '>=')
```

so just change your version to something else which must be greater than the upgraded version so that again first condition will be false and system will not check further and will connect without using TLS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble and stumbled upon the solution, and these are clearly related to changes in PHP 5.6 (which I'm not all together happy about).

1. The verify_peer and verify_peer_name are now by default set to true - requiring an extra level of security between the two machines involved in a streamed port.  I don't want this when I'm dealing with SMTP, the STARTTLS encryption is enough for me.
   So turn these off I added some code to the Net/SMTP.php file

   $options = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer_name' => false, 'verify_peer' => false));

   $result = $this->_socket->connect($this->host, $this->port,
                                             $persistent, $timeout, $options);
2. The socket timeout default specified in php.ini is not being used by this function.  So I changed the default in 'smtp.php' to:

   $timeout = 60; // previously null;

Hope that helps somebody else.
Cheers
Murray